# How to change the color of each ellipse in an array in Processing?

Tags: colors, processing, orbit

I'm trying to figure out how to change the colors of the three ellipses gravitating around the center ellipse. At the moment they are all red, but I would like to have one be green, one be red, one be yellow for example. Can anyone think of a way to do that?

This is my Processing code:

```
class OrbitalBody {

float ox, oy, x, y, m, a;

OrbitalBody(float originX, float originY, float startX, float startY, float mass, float speed) {
        ox = originX;
        oy = originY;
        x = startX;
        y = startY;
        m = mass;
        a = speed / 200;
}

void update() {
// creates the orbit;

float nx = (x-ox) * cos(a) - (y-oy) * sin(a),
      ny = (x-ox) * sin(a) + (y-oy) * cos(a);
      x = nx+ox;
          y = ny+oy;
}

void draw() {
// defines the color of the ellipses, now:red;
fill(255,0,0);
ellipse(x,y,m,m);
}
}

ArrayList<OrbitalBody> bodies = new ArrayList<OrbitalBody>();
int mx, my;


void setup() {
size(420, 420);
mx = width/2;
my = height/2;


// distances([3]bodies-(mx,my) is equal. Meaning all three bodies rotate on the same orbit, value now: mx-100;

fill(0,255,0);
bodies.add(new OrbitalBody(mx, my, mx-100, my, 10, 10));
fill(0);
bodies.add(new OrbitalBody(mx, my, mx-100, my, 20, 3));
bodies.add(new OrbitalBody(mx, my, mx-100, my, 5, 13));

ellipseMode(CENTER);
}

void draw() {

// defines background color, now:white;
background(255);
noStroke();

// defines center cercle color value, now:pink;
// second value:alpha channel;
fill(#ec5b94,80); 

// mx and my are the coordinates of the center pink cercle;
ellipse(mx,my,50,50);
for(OrbitalBody b: bodies) {
          b.update();
          b.draw();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could instantiate each OrbitalBody with a color parameter and then use that parameter in OrbitalBody's draw method.

Basically, the class would look something like:

```
class OrbitalBody {

    float ox, oy, x, y, m, a;
    color c;

    OrbitalBody(float originX, float originY, float startX, float startY, float mass, float speed, color bodyColor) {
        // Do stuff
        c = bodyColor;
    }

    void draw() {
        fill(c);
        ellipse(x,y,m,m);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately instantiating each OrbitalBody with a color parameter doesn't resolve the issue: all three ellipses still share the same color...

Comment: Yes, this solution resolve the issue! But you need create these orbital with different color ... or you missed something else so look to whole updated code [HERE](http://pastebin.com/G94hrj2A)

Comment: You're right!! This makes a lot of sense. Thanks so much for taking the time to look over the code :)